# ActiveMQ: how can I deliver all messages in a queue to many consumers?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a produser sending messages to the queue and two clients, that need to recieve all the messages from this queue. I considered using a topic whith durable subscribers, but I need consumers to recieve all messages even if they have been down for some time. Is there any solution for my case?

Answer (score 2):

If you need all clients to get a copy of the same persistent message  you'll want to use a [Virtual Destination](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).  You'll have to have each client listen to its own queue, but either method mentioned in the link will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Erik! As I understand, the producer should send messages to some topic whith prefix "VirtualTopic." And customers should read from topics whith "Customer.customer-name.VirtualTopic." prefix. Unfortunatly, I didn't manage to find any configuration example. Could you give the one, please?

Comment: There is nothing to to configure. It's all driven by name.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, Petter! It's more clear now :) I've managed to send messages to VirtualTopic and to recieve them by both cunsumers, but there is one confusing moment about message persistence. Will the consumer recieve messages that was sent by producer before this consumer first connection to the broker?

Comment: And one more question: if the producer sends messages to many VirtualTopics and consumers unaware about VirtualTopics names, can they get  the messages using wildcards (i.e. VirtualTopic.> ) ?

Comment: Messages won't be sent to a virtual topic queue until it is created that matches the pattern you specified.  Never tried the wild card myself and would personally recommend against it. Even if it does work you'd potentially be back in the same boat because you'd be competing for all messages that matched that wild card.

Comment: Thank you, Erik! So is there any way to create virtual topic queues for two consumers automaticaly when a new VirtualTopic created?